# Single method to return an instance of different generic type of a class

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class as follows:

```
MyClass<T>
{
    ....
}
```

---

Now, what I want create a single generic method,say for example `public MyClass<T> getMyClassInstance(Type t){...}`,  in which I pass a type and this method gives an instance of `MyClass` with that type.

---

See the following  examples.

1. If I call this method as follows, `getMyClassInstance(Integer_type)`, then it returns the `MyClass<Integer>` instance.
2. Similarly, if I call this method as follows, `getMyClassInstance(String_type)`, then it returns the `MyClass<String>` instance.

How shall I write this method? If it can't be done, is there any alternative way or another better way to do something like this?

Comment: Do you not want to use a constructor for this? If so, is it because you want singletons, or something else?

Comment: What are `String_type` and `Integer_type` ? Are they `String.class` and `Integer.class` or something else?

Comment: This is really unclear. What do you have? What do you want? What is `Type` and `Integer_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple applications of this, you don't even need to pass in a `Type` or `Class` argument. Consider the following:

```
public <T> List<T> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

To use this is as simple as:

```
List<Integer> lst = getList();
```

The compiler will infer the type of the list desired.

Do note that you will get more flexibility from passing in a `Type` parameter, especially in cases where you may not know in advance what sort of `List` you want to get back. But this sort of syntax, IMHO, reads more naturally and *may* be suited to what you want to do. (I say "may" since you haven't provided a ton of details ...)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. After re-examining, I agree that this method is indeed better suited to my specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The `Type` class must carry the type parameter on it: `Type<T>`, so you can declare

```
<T> MyClass<T> getMyClassInstance(Type<T> t);
```

If you can't make that happen, then the compiler is blind.